# A VM box which auto reverts to a saved state automatically on power loss or shutdown

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, vmware-workstation

So I can't seem to find much online about how to do this, but essentially I'd like to be able to have a Virtual Machine box (could be either VirtualBox, VM Ware or maybe something else), which would initially be setup with programs etc. and then have the state saved. This VM would would then be booted up and you can share a folder and make changes to the system, but once the machine is shutdown or has a power loss the new state of the machine is instantly lost, and the machine then reverts back to the original defined state. Any files edited on the shared directory would still persist though on the host machine of course.

It's worth mentioning I'd like this to be a Windows box, however I'm not sure the guest OS should matter? You could imagine this being the same way Tails works as a live distribution and has no persistence. Another consideration / bonus question is; ideally any temporary VM disks / images would automatically be created in memory too somehow, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

## VMware Workstation Pro

1. Set up the VM how you want.
2. Power the VM off.
3. Open **VM > Settings > Hardware > Hard Disk > Advanced**.
4. Choose **Independent** and **Nonpersistent**.
5. Repeat steps 3-4 as desired for other virtual disks.
6. If you want non-persistent writes to the VM's disk to not be written to the host disk, set **VM > Settings > Options > General > Working directory** and set it to a directory on a RAM disk.

(I don't have the latest version of VMware Workstation Pro handy, so some of the settings might have moved in other versions.)

## VMware Player

The above also can be done for VMware Player, but doing so will require hand-editing the VM's `.vmx` configuration file:

1. Power the VM off and close VMware Player.
2. Open the VM's `.vmx` file in a text editor.
3. Find the entry for the virtual disk file that you want to be non-persistent.  It should look like `TYPE_NODE.fileName = "YourDiskFile.vmdk"` where `TYPE_NODE` would be something like `ide0:0`, `ide1:0`, `scsi0:0`, `sata0:0`, etc.
4. Add (or replace if it already exists) a corresponding entry `TYPE_NODE.mode = "independent-nonpersistent"` with the same `TYPE_NODE`.  For example:

   ```
   sata0:0.mode = "independent-non-persistent"
   ```
5. Repeat step 4 as desired for other virtual disks.
6. If you want non-persistent writes to the VM's disk to not be written to the host disk, add/replace an entry:

   ```
   workingDir = "R:\SomeDirectory"
   ```

   where `R:\SomeDirectory` corresponds to a RAM disk directory on your host. (If you're running on a Linux host, obviously use a POSIX path.)

---

A simpler approach for VMware Workstation Pro (but that doesn't do everything you want) would be to configure the VM to automatically revert a snapshot when the VM is powered off (under **VM > Settings > Options > Snapshots**).  However, if the VM process is suddenly terminated (e.g. from host power loss), then the VM will not be reverted when it's powered on again. That seems like it'd be a reasonable feature request (or bug report, depending on your point of view).